# Add filling between a line and axis, but only in the negative region

Tags: filling

For plots like the one shown below, what is the syntax for adding filling between particular lines and the axis, but only in the negative region:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
Plot[{(x - 1)^2 - 1/2, 0}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, None}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {None, LightGray}}}]
```

[image: Plot filled only below axis]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x] + 1/2}, {x, 0, 4 Pi},  
 Filling -> {2 -> {0, {Automatic, None}}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x] + 1/2}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {Axis, {Automatic, None}}}]
```

> ```
> same picture
> ```

You can also use `Filling` + [`FillingStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FillingStyle.html)

```
Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x] + 1/2}, {x, 0, 4 Pi},  
  Filling -> {2 -> 0},
  FillingStyle -> {Opacity[.3, Red], None}]
```

[image]

**Note:** For some reason, `FillingStyle -> {Automatic, None}` does not work.